# Getting "org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException while creating a project using Springboot+OracleDB+JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am trying to work on a POC in Spring Boot to implement CRUD operations on an Oracle DB using JPA repository.

The API calls on my controller are working well but when I try to inject JPA repository, the application failed to start with below exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error
creating bean with name 'employeeController': Unsatisfied dependency
expressed through field 'employeeRepo': Error creating bean with name
'employeeRepo' defined in com.example.springjpaoracle.repo.EmployeeRepo
defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on SpringjpaOracleApplication: 
Not a managed type: class com.example.springjpaoracle.pojo.Employee
```

Please find the project structure and code below.

[image: Project Structure]

Main Class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringjpaOracleApplication {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringjpaOracleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Employee.class:

```
package com.example.springjpaoracle.pojo;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="employees")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private double salary;
    
    
    public Employee(String name, double salary) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", salary=" + salary + "]";
    }
    
}
```

EmployeeController.java: (with dummy API call)

```
package com.example.springjpaoracle.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.springjpaoracle.pojo.Employee;
import com.example.springjpaoracle.repo.EmployeeRepo;

@RestController
public class EmployeeController {
    
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepo employeeRepo;
    
    @PostMapping("/employee")
    public String postEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        System.out.println(employee.getName());
        System.out.println(employee.getSalary());
        return "Employee Added Successfully "+employee.toString();
    }   
}
```

EmployeeRepo.java:

```
package com.example.springjpaoracle.repo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.example.springjpaoracle.pojo.Employee;

public interface EmployeeRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

application.properties:

```
#DB Config
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
spring.datasource.username=suryamokka
spring.datasource.password=surya1995
spring.datasource.driver-class-oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: Did you add componentscan and tried to scan all packages? if employee repo is entity than use entityscan and try again

Comment: EmployeeRepo is not an Entity but a repo so do I need to use Component annotation on that interface and include ComponentScan annotation in my main class?

Comment: try using @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.netsurfingzone") and mention the base package and also the class path correctly. Try somehthing like this @ComponentScan(
    basePackageClasses = YourClass.class, 
    useDefaultFilters = false,
    includeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = YourClass.class)
    })

Comment: I am a real novice to this thing. Could You please be clear which class do I need to add in the place of "Your class"? and please confirm whether I need to place that ComponentScan annotation on main class or not? And should I place @Component class annotation on which I will refer in the place of "YourClass"?

Comment: use the repo class in yourclass and yes you have to add the componentscan in your main class. @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.springjpaoracle") like this. kindly refer this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning

Comment: But, the repo I have implemented is an interface not a class Edit : EmployeeRepo is an interface

Comment: its a bean so you have to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Repository
```

The above annotation is missing. You can use this annotation on EmployeeRepo.java file just above declaring the interface.

You will also need to add `@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.example.springjpaoracle")`
as Murali has suggested in SpringjpaOracleApplication right before declaring it as an annotation.

Hope this helps.